# java String split(String, int)

Tags: java, string, split

Really confusing about these two methods, having looked into the API doc of [split (String, int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) , 
still not sure when empty space will emerge.

For example

```
String s="boo:and:foo"
s.split("o", -2);
//the result, according to doc is { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
//why there is only one "" string in the front, while two "" in the back?
```

My thought after some testing is whenever there is consecutive match, in this case oo, there will be an additional "" , for the last trailing ""
    It is because of a match right before the end of String + consecutive match, resulting in **two** (the match right before the start of string will also result in a leading "")

Some confirmation needed.

Comment: because if you pass a negative (or greater then the amount of elements it would split) value to the `split(String,int)` method it will also include the trailing empty string, which is why `foo` creates two empty strings.

Comment: why two trailing "" then, any elabration? I understand why there should have, what I want to confirm is why there is two "" in the end.

Comment: " The array returned by this method contains each substring of this string that is terminated by another substring that matches the given expression OR is terminated by the end of the string." (added caps for emphasis).

Comment: try to split foo `food` logical by the parameter. It would be `"f" , "", "d"`.
Now lets go to `foo`. This would, like `food` create three elements `"f", "", ""` with two empty strings. Since in your case `foo` is the last element the normal `split(String)` method would exclude the traling empty string element. By providing a negative integer you just make sure that these are getting included.

Answer (score 2):

First of, lets start by checking what the logical result of a normal split operation would be. Lets take `one:two:three:four` as an example. You would expect, if you would split by `:`, to get the following result.

```
one
two
three
four
```

Lets add an other delimiter to the end of the `String`. Now it looks like `one:two:three:four:`. If we would be splitting this now, we would get the same result. This is due to the `split(String)` method defintion, which leaves out trailing empty strings. The same would happen if you would add more delimiters to the end of the string `one:two:three:four::::`. The result by using `split(String)` would be the same again, since like in the previous example it would exclude trailing empty string elements.

If you would like to include these elements, then you could use the `split(String,int)` function, which, if you provide a negative `int`, would include empty trailing strings. from the documentation of the method for the parameter `limit`, which is the `int`.

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length. If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and trailing empty strings will be discarded.

by passing it as negative we would get, for the string `one:two:three:four::`, the following result:

```
one
two
three
four
""
""
```

The same is happening for you example now. 
It does notice, that the word `foo` would create two empty trailing String elements at the end of the array, and will include them.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question by `int limit` parameter, let's say this parameter is limit *n*. But, you need to understand on how to split a `String` manually as I made on this table.

[image: split]

I use `"o"` as regular expression (regex) to split the `String`. Now, look at cell D2 and E2, and cell L2 and M2. There is a `null` character between `"o"` and `"o"`, it is `""`.

Because of the regular expression exists on the last `String` characters (cell M2), add single `""` to behind of the `String` characters. Likewise if the regular expression exists on the first `String` characters, add add single `""` to the first characters of the `String`.

So the `String` array will be:

```
string[0] ---> contains ---> "b"
string[1] ---> contains ---> ""
string[2] ---> contains ---> ":and:f"
string[3] ---> contains ---> ""
string[4] ---> contains ---> ""
```

Let's name this array with `splitted_string`.

---

### Zero limit

`split(regex, 0)` is equivalent with `split(String regex)` and doesn't include the last `String` characters that are empty. If you look at the table, you can see that cell L4 and N4 are empty `String`, so it will be ignored. For example:

```
String str = "boo:and:foo";
String[] a = str.split("o", 0);

for (String x : a)
    System.out.println("split(\"o\", 0)\t = " + x);

// Will give the same result with:
String[] b = str.split("o");
for (String x : b)
    System.out.println("split(\"o\")\t= " + x);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
split("o", 0)    = b
split("o", 0)    = 
split("o", 0)    = :and:f
split("o")  = b
split("o")  = 
split("o")  = :and:f
```

---

### Positive limit

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)):

> If the limit n is greater than zero then the pattern will be applied at most *n* - 1 times, the array's length will be no greater than n, and the array's last entry will contain all input beyond the last matched delimiter.

**Example 1:**

```
String str = "boo:and:foo";

String[] a = str.split("o", 2);
System.out.println("Length = " + a.length);
for (String x : a)
    System.out.println("split(\"o\", 2)\t = " + x);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Length = 2
split("o", 2)   = b
split("o", 2)   = o:and:foo
```

The pattern is applied *n* - 1 times, i.e. 2 - 1 = 1 times. Means that only the first `"o"` will be removed.

**Example 2:**

```
String[] b = str.split("o", 7);
System.out.println("Length = " + b.length);
for (String x : b)
    System.out.println("split(\"o\", 7)\t = " + x);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Length = 5
split("o", 7)   = b
split("o", 7)   = 
split("o", 7)   = :and:f
split("o", 7)   = 
split("o", 7)   =
```

There are only four characters `"o"` to be removed, but the pattern is applied *n* - 1 times, i.e. 7 - 1 = 6 times. Because of the application of this pattern is greater than total of characters `"o"`, so that all characters `"o"` will be removed.

Unlike `split(regex, 0)` and `split(regex)`, the result may be followed by empty `String`, i.e. `""`.

---

### Negative limit

From the docs:

> If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length.

If you enter any negative integer as the limit, the pattern will be applied as `split(regex, 0)` or `split(regex)`, but includes all empty `String` characters. For example:

```
String str = "boo:and:foo";
String[] a = str.split("o", -1);
System.out.println("Length = " + a.length);
for (String x : a)
    System.out.println("split(\"o\", -1)\t = " + x);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Length = 5
split("o", -1)  = b
split("o", -1)  = 
split("o", -1)  = :and:f
split("o", -1)  = 
split("o", -1)  =
```

If you are still confused, look at the table and `splitted_string` above again.